# Access - VBA - Get row number by criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

Looking at the following code, how can I receive the row number for a user using the variable `usern`?
I can check whether a user exists using the `DCount` function as can be seen. Once received the row number, I would like to use it to navigate to that entry using  `DoCmd.GoToRecord`. `GoToRecord` itself works already. I just cannot find a way to receive the row number...

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

Dim usern As String
Dim count As Integer

usern = Environ("Username")

count = DCount("name_", "Fragebogen", "name_='" & usern & "'")

DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Fragebogen", acGoTo, 3

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [FindFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194787.aspx) method?

> Locates the first record in a dynaset - or - snapshot-type Recordset
>   object that satisfies the specified criteria and makes that record the
>   current record.

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

rs.FindFirst "name_ = '" & Environ("Username") & "'"

If Not rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
Else
    MsgBox "No match was found.", vbExclamation
Emd If
```

Comment: Was just writing up a similar answer. Add the `Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark` to navigate to the record, then your answer is complete.

Comment: Adding your Me.Bookmark and it works like a charme. Thank you guys! Very much appreciated